# Bootstrap elements not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in my project and it's working fine in all other browsers except internet explorer. I have added the following lines in the Page Head

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> 


 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

After adding these lines the UI is working fine but bootstrap built in features not working for example : Tab , collapse is not working on internet explorer.
Kindly let me know if you have any solution Thanks.

Comment: Check the documentation template where they added two more meta tags: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Comment: I've added these tags but still tabs and collapse not working :(

Comment: these are the tags  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Can you add your complete html page with all the bootstrap references?

Comment: I am working on Asp.net that's why Files are linked in Master page and tab function is in other page .. which page should i've to upload  ?

Comment: Are you running a web form application with .aspx? Lets start with the master page (where you store your bootstrap library?)